# Show that the number of nodes in a complete m-ary tree of height h is given by ((m ^ (h + 1)) - 1) / (m-1), where m is an integer greater than 1.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I proved a similar exercise [((3 ^ (h + 1)) - 1) / 2] using induction.
In this case I knew that ((3 ^ (h + 1)) - 1) / 2 = ∑ (h, i = 0) 3 ^ i.
But in that case I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give an algebraic derivation using the formula for partial sum of geometric series. For an intuitive argument, interpret the tree as the structure of a single elimination tournament in a game where $m$ players compete and only $1$ wins, in which there are initially $m^h$ teams corresponding to the leaves of the tree. Each non-leaf is a game with $1$ winner and $m-1$ losers.

Let $g$ be the number of games (i.e. non-leaf nodes). Since there are $m-1$ losers in each game and one final champion, counting all the teams we have

$m^h = 1 + g(m-1)$ and thus $g = (m^h - 1)/(m - 1)$.

Then the number of nodes in the tree is

$g + m^h = (m^h - 1)/(m - 1) + m^h = (m^h - 1 + m(m^h) - 1(m^h))/(m - 1) = (m(m^h) - 1)/(m - 1)$ as desired.